# Free solution for multiple-source audio mixing

Tags: audio

I'm looking to do live broadcasts of video games, which require mixing together the game audio as well as microphone audio.

In the case of an actual game system being used, I have external hardware that can mix the console audio, and my microphone. However, in the case of a game being played on the computer itself, I have a problem.

When specifying the audio source, I can only choose 'computer audio', or my microphone.

I believe some means to accomplishing this are Rogue Amoeba's [Audio Hijack Pro](http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) or Ambrosia's [Wiretap Anywhere](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wta/), but each of these have a cost associated that is a bit more than I'm able to pay at the moment (and in the case of Wiretap Anywhere, MUCH more than I'm able to pay).

Is there some sort of audio mixing software that will allow me to create a virtual device consisting of my computer audio (or a specific application(s') audio) and my microphone audio, as one input device, suitable for using in another application?

Answer (score 1):

Search in Spotlight for "Audio Midi Setup." It looks like this:

[image: Audio Midi Setup]

Clicking the little "+" sign in the bottom-left corner and clicking "Create Aggregate Device" will allow you to combine various inputs and outputs on your system into a single one.

Comment: I know of this feature, but it does not answer the question. Creating an aggregate audio device does not turn an output (built-in output) into an input. You can use an aggregate audio device to output on multiple speakers/outputs at once, and yes it is possible to join inputs and outputs into a single device, but you cannot use it to turn output into a recordable input. Whatever the source type is (input/output) will remain the same in an aggregate device.

Comment: Could you use the tool to mix all of your sources into one output, then plug it into another device for recording?

Comment: I do have the capability to hardware mix, I just don't want to introduce it chiefly due to limited desk space. And because everything's already on my computer, I shouldn't (IMO) *have to* introduce anything besides software.

Comment: Do you need exceptional quality? If you're willing to sacrifice a bit, you could plug it into an iPod or other device that can record audio. Or, if you want to have fun with it, you could mix it together with the Audio MIDI Setup tool, then run a cable from your headphone jack to your mic jack, and record using GarageBand or Audacity. It is a bit odd, but I have made it work in the past.

Comment: I'm not aware of how to use the iPhone as a live microphone. How did you accomplish this?

Comment: You may want to put out a new question to see if there is "an app for that."

Comment: I don't know if you're still looking for information, but I just ran across this: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14067/soundflower. Might that help?

Comment: I have started using Soundflower, and it has indeed solved my problems. I meant to write up the answer for it, but never had.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.