# Master volume control for multiple audio output OSX

Tags: audio

Few of the third party apps like soundflower and boom used to provide a master volume control for multiple audio output on OSX (aka combining USB audio output and 3.5mm output etc). None of the mentioned apps work anymore, say soundflower app cannot be loaded and boom 2 has a volume control but will not change the volume of multiple output devices. Is there someway on 10.11 to control the master volume of multiple audio output?

Comment: And what's wrong with the good old volume up/down buttons?

Comment: @JohnRamos volume control will be disabled when using multiple output devices.

Comment: Ok then. Try adding volume control to menubar?

Comment: @JohnRamos are you messing with me?

Comment: I didn't mean to be, just tried it and realized it didn't work as I imagined it would :|, sorry. Try this, maybe? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38196/free-solution-for-multiple-source-audio-mixing?rq=1

Comment: @JohnRamos that's for creating multiple-output devices, not for controlling its master volume.

Comment: Does the USB audio output have volume controls on it? Do you have one device specifically?

Comment: @JohnRamos the purpose of this is to control multiple devices' volume at once as if they are one device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioMate gives you control over individual devices on menubar but it cannot change a master volume control for multiple audio output. Soundflower has one flaw that all your device must have the same output or it will not run - for example all of them set to 48K Hz 2ch-16bit. If you have a 4ch USB and a 2ch 3.5cm you will need to change your 4ch USB to 2ch, likewise on bit rate and frequency.

Comment: It seems AudioMate is dead now?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this whilst searching for something else…

[MultiSoundChanger](https://github.com/rlxone/MultiSoundChanger) (freeware, open source)

> A small tool for changing sound volume even for aggregate devices cause native sound volume controller can't change volume of aggregate devices
>
> Features:
>
> - Changing sound volume of every device (even virtual aggregate device volume by changing volume of every device in aggregate device)
> - Changing default output device
> - Native appearance (looks like native volume controller)
> - Media keys support